# Spectrum colorpicker always shows black

Tags: javascript, spectrumjs

I'm using the spectrum color picker: https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/

On an input like this:

```
<input type="text" value="#0000FF" data-color="color_1">
```

And for my input I have the following JS:

```
$('[data-color]').spectrum({
    showInput: true,
    preferredFormat: 'hex',
    color: '#0000FF'
});
```

But neither the default input value or the override in my JS code are being used as the selected color. It ALWAYS shows as black.

Here is a fiddle showing it happening:

https://jsfiddle.net/4vgmh97L/3/

The console logs show that the spectrum value and input value are different... but should be the same... any ideas what's going on?

Comment: It also doesn't update the `value` of the input field. It doesn't do this in the demo on github either. Very strange.

Comment: Try this to get value $('[data-color]').spectrum('get');

Comment: @yogendarji Gives the color for black in tinyColor.

Comment: @yogendarji See updated fiddle and the console logs are different!